# Ruby on Rails: Need help updating db attribute in a nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, routes, nested

Let me preface this by saying, i'm pretty new to rails and programming.

I'm trying to make some links to toggle a boolean attribute on and off. I've essentially succeeded in doing it on a non-nested resource by doing the following:

Route:

```
resources :my_resource do
 get 'toggle_attribute', :on => :member
end
```

Controller:

```
def toggle_attribute
  @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
  @resource.toggle!(:attribute)
end
```

View: 
`<%= link_to "Toggle Resource", toggle_attribute_resource_path(@resource), :remote => true %>`

First, like I said above, this works on my non-nested route, however no matter what solution I try to add to the controller I can't get my link to flash a message or re-direct to anything when clicked, you click the button and nothing happens, you have to manually refresh to see the change.

Second, I can't figure out how to get this same sort of thing to work on a route that is nested like so:

Route:

```
resources :resource_1 do
resources :resource_2
end
```

Can anyone give me some tips?

Thanks a ton in advance. This stuff has been driving me batty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `remote => true`, you are telling it to make an ajax call. This means that you need to also add a toggle_attribute.js.erb file in your views folder and in that file use javascript to replace the link element or text with what you want.

Also make sure to respond to js by setting `respond_to :html, :js` at the top of your controller.

```
repond_to :html, :js
def toggle_attribute
  @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
  @resource.toggle!(:attribute)
end
```

toggle_attribute.js.erb :

```
$('#toggler').html("my new html here");
```

in view:

```
<%= link_to "Toggle Resource", toggle_attribute_resource_path(@resource), :remote => true, :id => "toggler"%>
```

Update:

For your nested route try this:

```
resources :resource_1 do
  resources :resource_2 do
    member do
      get :toggle_attribute
    end
  end
end
```

your path would be something like:

```
toggle_attribute_resource_1_resource_2_path(@resource, @resource2)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this was very helpful. I've now got it responding to my clicks on my un-nested resource. I'm still not sure about the routing for the nested resource though.

Comment: I added some stuff to my answer than will hopefully help.

Comment: You are a wizard! :D

Your updated version worked perfectly for my nested resource. Thank you so much!

PS. I'd upvote your answer if I had 15 rep. I'll come back and upvote it when I do. :)